# C# winforms: How to change DPI of the System.Drawing.BItmap?

Tags: c#, gdi+

I need to change the DPI of the System.Drawing.Bitmap object from the default value = 96 to e.g. 150. I couldn't find the answer how to do that so I ask here :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
result.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);
```